# On passing arguments to programs through array variables

Tags: zsh, quoting, array

NB: though the question below features `rsync`, it is *not* a question about `rsync`; it is a question about zsh arrays.

---

If I initialize the variable `EXCLUDES` like this

```
EXCLUDES=( --exclude=/foo --exclude=/bar --exclude=/baz )
```

then, when I run the command

```
rsync -a $EXCLUDES / /some/target
```

...then I see that `/foo`, `/bar`, and `/baz` are indeed not copied to `/some/target`.

But now, suppose that `EXCLUDE_ITEMS` is something like this

```
EXCLUDE_ITEMS=( /foo /bar /baz )
```

...and I initialize EXCLUDE like this

```
EXCLUDES=()
for item in $EXCLUDE_ITEMS
do
    EXCLUDES+=( "--exclude='$item'" )
done
```

...or like this

```
EXCLUDES=( $(for item in $EXCLUDE_ITEMS; do echo "--exclude='$item'"; done) )
```

...then in either case, after I run

```
rsync -a $EXCLUDES / /some/target
```

...I now find that the excluded directories have *not* been excluded from the transfer.

Since the command lines (as typed on the terminal) are all identical, I must conclude that there is a difference between the explicitly initialized `EXCLUDES` from those that get initialized by iterating over `EXCLUDE_ITEMS`, but I cannot figure out what it is.

How can I initialize `EXCLUDE` from the items in `EXCLUDE_ITEMS` so that the latter indeed get excluded when I run

```
rsync -a $EXCLUDES / /some/target
```

---

PS: In fact, if I run

```
eval "rsync -a $EXCLUDES / /some/target"
```

...where `EXCLUDES` has been initialized in either of the `for`-loop-based ways shown above, then the directories named in `EXCLUDES` are indeed excluded, as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by writing `"--exclude='$item'"`, you're putting single quotes in the exclude pattern. So you're excluding `'/foo'` and so on, but you probably don't have any files with names starting and ending with single quotes.

You need to write

```
EXCLUDES+=( "--exclude=$item" )
```

or, since this is zsh, you don't need double quotes: just write

```
EXCLUDES+=( --exclude=$item )
```

or, since this is zsh, you don't need a loop: just use the [`^` parameter expansion option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-parameter-expansion):

```
rsync -a --exclude=$^EXCLUDE_ITEMS …
```

In ksh or bash, you would need the loop and double quotes throughout:

```
EXCLUDES=()
for item in "${EXCLUDE_ITEMS[@]}";  do
  EXCLUDES+=( "--exclude=$item" )
done
rsync -a "${EXCLUDES[@]}" …
```

Comment: Even though I've been using zsh for years (decades even), I have never managed to fully understand quoting...  Setting `EXCLUDES=( --exclude='/foo' --exclude='/bar' --exclude='/baz' )` causes no problem, despite the single quotes.  But, as you point out, using `EXCLUDES+=( "--exclude='$item'" )` *does* lead to problems.  I realize that it all has to do with the relative timing of the various expansions and whatnot that happen during zsh's parsing.  This is what I cannot keep track of, and is at the root of 90% of my problems with zsh.

Comment: @kjo In `"--exclude='$item'"`, the single quotes are between double quotes. Since they're quoted, they don't have a special meaning, they're just the `'` character.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I see that.  I can rationalize these things after-the-fact (i.e. when I know where to focus), but to sort out all of the possible ins and outs ahead of time is, for me, the equivalent of multiplying two 5-digit numbers in my head; it's beyond what I can do easily.  In no other programming context do I have such difficulties.  For me shell quoting is pure hell.